# LDAP and Active Directory Learning Curve

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We are thinking about using LDAP with Active Directory for user management of many web applications instead of a custom relational database solution.  Is there a high learning curve when doing this or is it easy as 1,2,3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LDAP a bit funny and a bit "different" than traditional data stores - so there's definitely a learning curve involved.

The most challenging part would be to get a "grip" on the LDAP paths and how to build those up and use them. Also: permissions to connect to LDAP are always a bit issue. And if you want to start searching for objects in your LDAP store, then the rather tricky syntax of LDAP filters might also be a bit of a challenge to wrap your brain around :-)

If you intend to talk to and use Active Directory on Windows, then you should definitely check out the [SelfADSI](http://www.selfadsi.org/index.htm) site with lots of useful information.

You didn't mention what language/programming environment you intend to use - if you're on .NET 3.5 or newer (C#, VB.NET), you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here....     
}

// find the group in question
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

// if found....
if (group != null)
{
   // iterate over members
   foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
      // do whatever you need to do to those members
   }
}
```

The new `S.DS.AM` namespace makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD in C#/VB.NET!

Answer (score 0):

See also: ["LDAP: Programming Practices"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/) for information on writing code for LDAP server interaction will be robust, insulated and desensitized from any vendor specific LDAP knowledge. Writing code with specific knowledge of an implementation will result in brittle, hard to maintain code that may experience unexpected results when an aspect of the server implementation changes, such as the server itself, or the configuration of the server, or load balancers, or anything related to the infrastructure.

Avoid writing Microsoft specific code or creating Microsoft specific configurations wherever possible. Stick to the LDAP standards documents to the letter.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Wouldn't using LDAP conform to a cross platform solution with the underline data source being Active Directory?